# Android - I can see the data when I debug but the log.cat shows error : fail to open database error

Tags: android, sqlite

I am so confused, I was able to see the information from the database, however, I noticed there is an error code showing in the log.cat

Also, the page that with `getReadableDatabase` fine.
but for `getWritableDatabase`, it breaks.

but this error show in the logcat for both cases...

```
1342-1342/com.package/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Failed to open database 'data/data/com.package/databases/'
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14):Could not open database
```

=================================================================================

```
 public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        DATABASE_PATH =  "data/data/com.package/databases/";
        db = getWritableDatabase();
    }



@Override
public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
    try {
        if (db != null) {
            if (db.isOpen()) {
                return db;
            }
        }
        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems there is no database, cause the file should be inside ./Databases

Comment: - nousefornmae, if there's no database how come I can read the data?
@Opiatefuchs I am new to Android, my database file is in the internal storage so I still need write permissions?

Comment: could You please show us some relevant part of Your code? No, You don´t...I haven´t seen it. but maybe a little bit of code would help..

Comment: Also possible its already open and you try to open it again

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I added some code from my database.class

Comment: i am wondering, why you override the "getWriteableDatabase" method. shouldne be nessecary

Comment: @nouseforname  for all my database function (CRUD) I have db.close(); at the end.

Comment: is your package really named "com.package"?

Comment: no, I removed the last part. it was com.something.something

Comment: ok but You use the right name in Your code?

Comment: Yes. it is the right name.

Comment: ok, but I am a little bit confused because of Your error message. usually it has to be Failed to open database 'data/data/com.package/databases/yourDatabase.db' or something similar. It seems that the database name is not extended. You have to write in Your getWritableDatabase Method: openDatabase(DATABASE_PATH+DATABASE_NAME)

Comment: @Opiatefuchs did not see your comment. but yes, we are at the same page. I added database name to the end of the databse path, then no error.

Fixed all problems. Now it works fine no breaking with GetWriteableDatabase and GetReadableDatabase
no error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited my post and added the answer but just for easy reading

Here is my answer

just add the actual database name to the end of the path, in my case

```
DATABASE_NAME = database.sqlite
```

so I change it from this one

```
public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        DATABASE_PATH =  "data/data/com.package/databases/";
        db = getWritableDatabase();
    }
```

to this one

```
public Database(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            DATABASE_PATH =  "data/data/com.package/databases/database.sqlite";
            db = getWritableDatabase();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample method of me, which shows how it works usually:

```
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public String getDbPath() {
    return db.getPath();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    try {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_DB);
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        if (Constant.DEBUG)
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
}

public void writeInDb(String sql) {
    if (db == null || !db.isOpen())
        db = getWritableDatabase();

    try {
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        if (Constant.DEBUG)
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
}
```

Also there i no need to hardode the db path, better use:

```
db.getPath();
```

the database is automatically created in the `Databases` folder